# Understanding Oath 2.0 Autorization Code Flow

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Why do we need first contact the Oath Auth endpoint to get an auth code, and then once we have received the auth code we need to contact the Oauth Auth endpoint again to get the access token so that we can call a webservice?

Why not just return the access token in the first step, after the user has signed in successfully?

Also, how does the webservice (API) then verify that the access token is legit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do we need first contact the Oath Auth endpoint to get an auth code, and then once we have received the auth code we need to contact the Oauth Auth endpoint again to get the access token so that we can call a webservice?

So the web service (or Relying Party) never sees the user's credentials.
And because of how this flow works, the user also cannot see the application's credentials.
User also can't get the access token to use it themselves, though that actually would not matter that much.. Implicit Grant Flow actually does what you want, allowing you to get an access token directly from the authorization endpoint. But that is mainly for Single Page Apps, for which that is the easiest option.
Authorization Code Grant flow allows the app to use a stronger authentication via a client secret or certificate.

This is called an *OAuth dance* by the way :)

> Why not just return the access token in the first step, after the user has signed in successfully?

See my mention above about Implicit Grant flow.

> Also, how does the webservice (API) then verify that the access token is legit?

By checking the digital signature. Azure AD (and B2C) publish public keys for the key pairs they use for signing at a well known endpoint.
The authentication pieces in an app must check the JWT signature is valid by the defined public key.